# Bacula Volume Retention and Automatic Recycling

Tags: bacula, backup

Will a bacula volume be recycled if:

- No more volumes are appendable
- The date of the last job on it is past the volume retention period
- Jobs on that volume are *not* past the job and file retention periods

This is the way the manual reads to me, but I saw a post saying all retention periods have to be up before a volume is recycled (which does make less sense to me).

Anyone know for sure from experience?

Comment: The manual is clear: "Note, that when the Volume Retention period has been reached, and it is necessary to obtain a new volume, Bacula will prune both the Job and the File records." "This means that all the retentions periods are applied in turn and that the shorter period is the one that effectively takes precedence."